# How do I get pickadate.js working with the JAWS screenreader?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have an application that is in the late stages that uses [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/). It's been reported to me that JAWS does not work with the date picker since the arrow keys are required to select a day and they are already mapped to something else in JAWS.

Is there a good way to get around this issue and still make the datepicker accessible for JAWS users? Any insight would be appreciated. Still learning about accessibility on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pickadate.js version 3.5.5 then the arrow keys will work properly, however it is using `aria-activedescendant` to track the currently 'focusssed' date and this is not yet supported in all screen readers (does not work for example on OS X with VoiceOver and as far as I know also does not work with JAWS)

You could change the code https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js of the datepicker to use ARIA live regions to announce the dates as the user uses the arrow keys. It is based on jQuery and there is a jQuery library that you could integrate to do this:

https://github.com/dylanb/a11yfy

You would essentially call `jQuery.a11yfy.assertiveAnnounce(msg);` every time the `aria-activedescendant` changed with the contents of that cell.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I am indeed using 3.5.5. The solution seems a bit confusing to me, but I'll look into it.

Comment: how to detect aria-activedescendant have been changed to call assertiveAnnounce(msg)

Comment: Your code must be setting it, so no need to detect it. If you did not write the code then you can use a DOM observer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver to look for DOM mutations.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate date picker is available here http://freqdec.github.io/datePicker/, it claims to be fully accessible but it also seems to suffer from the arrow keys not working (I tested in NVDA, I suspect JAWS will have the same issue).

However, Look at demo #9 here: http://freqdec.github.io/datePicker/demo/ it features a static date (not a popup) picker which does work with NVDA, it even dutifully announces each date as you use the arrow keys to navigate around the control.